# Build LINQ query in a loop

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a LINQ query (which will be executed against a DbContext), which I start off by building using some conditions I know of beforehand.

```
var r = from p in db.People
        where blah
        select p;
```

I then have a bunch of search conditions, provided as an array (string[]). If I wanted to do an AND, this is easy:

```
foreach (string s in searchParameters)
{
      r = from r1 in r
          where r1.field == s
          select r1;
}
```

However, I now have a need to use these parameters in an OR fashion. One solution is to do something like:

```
var results = new List<IEnumerable<RowType>>();
foreach (string s in searchParameters)
{
      var r2 = from r1 in r
          where r1.field == s
          select r1;
      results.Add(r2);
}
```

and then, at the end, do a UNION of all the entries in "results". But, this would translate to a much more needlessly complicated query on the DB, and also introduce potentially duplicate rows which I'd then need to de-dup.

Is there an easy as well as efficient way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to make use of `PredicateBuilder`, If i am getting correctly you are making single query and you need conditions in it

```
IQueryable<Product> SearchProducts (params string[] keywords)
{
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();

  foreach (string keyword in keywords)
  {
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
  }
  return dataContext.Products.Where (predicate);
}
```

[Dynamically Composing Expression Predicates](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [System.Linq.Dynamic package available on Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/). You can also follow [this guide](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions) on how to use the package.

In your case, I believe the query could be:

```cs
var query = IQueryable<DataType>();
foreach(string parameter in searchParameters)
{
   query = query.Where("fieldName ==" + parameter );
}

// call the LINQ query at the end when all the conditions are built
var results = query.Select(q => q.field).ToList();
```

This may work for your case, otherwise you could use a predicate builder as per Pranay's suggestion.

Comment: people can just give some down votes if they aren't satisfied. I simply wanted to see if I can be of any help.

Comment: sunderedTomato: it looks like your solution will cause all the predicates to be ANDed (and not OR-ed), correct?

Comment: yes this will perform an and .